# the number of ways of selecting numbers, that multiplied together, result in the given number

Tags: python, algorithm, math, data-structures

I have a programming problem which looks like this.
Returns the number of ways of selecting numbers in the first
argument that multiplied together, result in the second
argument.

Recall that the product of an empty sequence of numbers equals 1.

You can assume that the function is called with a list of
integers as first argument, and an integer as second argument.
​
​Code structure with test case look like this.

```
def f(numbers, desired_product):
    '''
    >>> f([2], 3)
    0
    >>> f([2, 3, 5], 11)
    0
    >>> f([1], 1)
    2
    >>> f([1, 1, 1], 1)
    8
    >>> f([2, 3], 2)
    1
    >>> f([1, 2, 3], 2)
    2
    >>> f([1, 2, 3], 6)
    2
    >>> f([3, 8, 7, 3, 7, 3, 7, 8, 5], 3 * 3 * 7)
    9
    >>> f([2, 5, 7, 11] * 4, 2 * 5 * 7)
    64
    >>> f([1, 2, 5, 7, 11] * 4, 2 * 5 * 7)
    1024
    >>> f(list(range(1, 10)), 40)
    4
    '''
    return -1
    # REPLACE THE RETURN STATEMENT ABOBVE WITH YOUR CODE
​
​
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

I understand the problem but didn't understand the

```
>>> f([1], 1)
    

2
```

test case. Can anyone help me understand the test case and provide me the solution?

Comment: "Recall that the product of an empty sequence of numbers equals 1." So `prod([]) = prod([1]) = 1`

Comment: @Julien Oh that also explains `f([1, 1, 1], 1) = 8`!

Comment: @j1-lee how it comes 8?

Comment: It's like that { [ ], [1], [1], [1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1,1,1]} ?

Comment: You could bruteforce the problem by using function `powerset` from the recipes on the itertools documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 1):

I'll drop an outline, try to code it yourself (and do comment if you notice any mistake).

Firstly, we know f([], 1) = 1 and f([], x) = 0 for x != 1.

Consider `f([x0, x1, ...], y)`. Then we have two choices: use x0 or not use x0. If we use x0, then the result is the same as `f([x1, ...], y / x0)` (note that this choice is invalid if y is not a multiple of x0). If we do not use x0, then the result is the same as `f([x1, ...], y)`.

Now we have a recurrence relation, we can either implement it naïvely or use dynamic programming.